# How can I use decltype to get the address of some class type's member function?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose the following code:

```
class MyTest
{
public:

    void CallFoo()
    {
    }

    MyTest()
    {
        std::function<void()> func = &decltype(*this)::CallFoo;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyTest t;
}
```

What I have there won't compile, but essentially I need to be able to use `decltype` to get the address to a member function of the type of `*this`. Normally you'd just do `&MyTest::CallFoo`.

Is this possible? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: How about `std::function<void()> func = [this]{ CallFoo(); };`?

Comment: Sensible response but unfortunately I have an ulterior motive: This is being done my macro magic and your case won't work for that. As much as it pains me, I need to see if the case above works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
&std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>::CallFoo
```

or in C++11 (sorry, just noticed tag)

```
&std::remove_pointer<decltype(this)>::type::CallFoo
```

The problem with what you have is that `decltype(*this)` gives `MyTest&` rather than `MyTest` since `*this` is an lvalue.

However, `std::function<void()>` won't work, since a non-static member function of `MyTest` needs to be called with a `MyTest*` to act as `this`. You can use `std::function<void(MyTest*)>` or `std::function<void(decltype(this))>` if you want the caller to specify the object. If you want to bind `this`, you should probably just use a lambda, it's much easier:

```
auto func = [this]{ CallFoo(); };
```

Comment: The first half of your response is the answer. The `std::function` thing was an oversight on my part, and a contrived example. It was my attempt to somehow justify the code belonging in the body of the constructor of the class. I'm really not storing it that way though. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: Contains a macro. Use responsibly.

Use the following macro to make `decltype` work "sensibly" with references.

```
template<class T> struct TypeOf { typedef typename std::remove_reference<T>::type type; };
#define TYPE(x) TypeOf<decltype(x)>::type
```

Comment: Why `TypeOf` when you can just use `std::remove_reference` directly?

Comment: @Barry Too much typing.

Comment: Since you `#define`d it, you actually harden your work.

Comment: @Zereges How? I know macros are evil, but so is typing 30 characters for a simple thing.

Comment: Even assuming that there's a need for such a macro, there's not much point using `TypeOf`.

Comment: couldn't you have used a template alias instead of a struct `TypeOf`?

Comment: Please suggest a better alternative as I use this and do know it's ugly (I don't usually code like that honest). I want the syntax to require no more characters than normally required for `decltype`